# AUC is not definied[sic] when there is no positive class in the data

Tags: c#, ml.net

I am facing the following issue when attempting to train a model:

```
Inferring Columns ...
Creating Data loader ...
Loading data ...
Exploring multiple ML algorithms and settings to find you the best model for ML task: binary-classification
For further learning check: https://aka.ms/mlnet-cli
|     Trainer                              Accuracy      AUC    AUPRC  F1-score  Duration #Iteration             |
[Source=AutoML, Kind=Trace] Channel started
[Source=AutoML, Kind=Trace] Evaluating pipeline xf=ColumnConcatenating{ col=Features:V1,V2,V3,V4,V5,V6} xf=Normalizing{ col=Features:Features} tr=AveragedPerceptronBinary{}  cache=+
[Source=AutoML, Kind=Error] Pipeline crashed: xf=ColumnConcatenating{ col=Features:V1,V2,V3,V4,V5,V6} xf=Normalizing{ col=Features:Features} tr=AveragedPerceptronBinary{}  cache=+ . Exception: System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: AUC is not definied when there is no positive class in the data
Parameter name: PosSample
   at Microsoft.ML.Data.EvaluatorBase`1.AucAggregatorBase`1.ComputeWeightedAuc(Double& unweighted)
   at Microsoft.ML.Data.BinaryClassifierEvaluator.Aggregator.Finish()
   at Microsoft.ML.Data.BinaryClassifierEvaluator.<>c__DisplayClass32_0.<GetAggregatorConsolidationFuncs>b__0(UInt32 stratColKey, ReadOnlyMemory`1 stratColVal, Aggregator agg)
   at Microsoft.ML.Data.EvaluatorBase`1.ProcessData(IDataView data, RoleMappedSchema schema, Func`2 activeColsIndices, TAgg aggregator, AggregatorDictionaryBase[] dictionaries)
   at Microsoft.ML.Data.EvaluatorBase`1.Microsoft.ML.Data.IEvaluator.Evaluate(RoleMappedData data)
   at Microsoft.ML.Data.BinaryClassifierEvaluator.Evaluate(IDataView data, String label, String score, String predictedLabel)
   at Microsoft.ML.AutoML.BinaryMetricsAgent.EvaluateMetrics(IDataView data, String labelColumn)
   at Microsoft.ML.AutoML.RunnerUtil.TrainAndScorePipeline[TMetrics](MLContext context, SuggestedPipeline pipeline, IDataView trainData, IDataView validData, String labelColumn, IMetricsAgent`1 metricsAgent, ITransformer preprocessorTransform, FileInfo modelFileInfo, DataViewSchema modelInputSchema, AutoMLLogger logger)
[Source=AutoML, Kind=Trace] 1   NaN 00:00:00.3095729    xf=ColumnConcatenating{ col=Features:V1,V2,V3,V4,V5,V6} xf=Normalizing{ col=Features:Features} tr=AveragedPerceptronBinary{}  cache=+
|1    AveragedPerceptronBinary                  NaN      NaN      NaN       NaN       0.3          0             |
System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: AUC is not definied when there is no positive class in the data
Parameter name: PosSample
   at Microsoft.ML.Data.EvaluatorBase`1.AucAggregatorBase`1.ComputeWeightedAuc(Double& unweighted)
   at Microsoft.ML.Data.BinaryClassifierEvaluator.Aggregator.Finish()
   at Microsoft.ML.Data.BinaryClassifierEvaluator.<>c__DisplayClass32_0.<GetAggregatorConsolidationFuncs>b__0(UInt32 stratColKey, ReadOnlyMemory`1 stratColVal, Aggregator agg)
   at Microsoft.ML.Data.EvaluatorBase`1.ProcessData(IDataView data, RoleMappedSchema schema, Func`2 activeColsIndices, TAgg aggregator, AggregatorDictionaryBase[] dictionaries)
   at Microsoft.ML.Data.EvaluatorBase`1.Microsoft.ML.Data.IEvaluator.Evaluate(RoleMappedData data)
   at Microsoft.ML.Data.BinaryClassifierEvaluator.Evaluate(IDataView data, String label, String score, String predictedLabel)
   at Microsoft.ML.AutoML.BinaryMetricsAgent.EvaluateMetrics(IDataView data, String labelColumn)
   at Microsoft.ML.AutoML.RunnerUtil.TrainAndScorePipeline[TMetrics](MLContext context, SuggestedPipeline pipeline, IDataView trainData, IDataView validData, String labelColumn, IMetricsAgent`1 metricsAgent, ITransformer preprocessorTransform, FileInfo modelFileInfo, DataViewSchema modelInputSchema, AutoMLLogger logger)
[Source=AutoML, Kind=Trace] Evaluating pipeline xf=ColumnConcatenating{ col=Features:V1,V2,V3,V4,V5,V6} xf=Normalizing{ col=Features:Features} tr=SdcaLogisticRegressionBinary{}  cache=+
[Source=AutoML, Kind=Error] Pipeline crashed: xf=ColumnConcatenating{ col=Features:V1,V2,V3,V4,V5,V6} xf=Normalizing{ col=Features:Features} tr=SdcaLogisticRegressionBinary{}  cache=+ . Exception: System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: AUC is not definied when there is no positive class in the data
Parameter name: PosSample
   at Microsoft.ML.Data.EvaluatorBase`1.AucAggregatorBase`1.ComputeWeightedAuc(Double& unweighted)
   at Microsoft.ML.Data.BinaryClassifierEvaluator.Aggregator.Finish()
   at Microsoft.ML.Data.BinaryClassifierEvaluator.<>c__DisplayClass32_0.<GetAggregatorConsolidationFuncs>b__0(UInt32 stratColKey, ReadOnlyMemory`1 stratColVal, Aggregator agg)
   at Microsoft.ML.Data.EvaluatorBase`1.ProcessData(IDataView data, RoleMappedSchema schema, Func`2 activeColsIndices, TAgg aggregator, AggregatorDictionaryBase[] dictionaries)
   at Microsoft.ML.Data.EvaluatorBase`1.Microsoft.ML.Data.IEvaluator.Evaluate(RoleMappedData data)
   at Microsoft.ML.Data.BinaryClassifierEvaluator.Evaluate(IDataView data, String label, String score, String predictedLabel)
   at Microsoft.ML.AutoML.BinaryMetricsAgent.EvaluateMetrics(IDataView data, String labelColumn)
   at Microsoft.ML.AutoML.RunnerUtil.TrainAndScorePipeline[TMetrics](MLContext context, SuggestedPipeline pipeline, IDataView trainData, IDataView validData, String labelColumn, IMetricsAgent`1 metricsAgent, ITransformer preprocessorTransform, FileInfo modelFileInfo, DataViewSchema modelInputSchema, AutoMLLogger logger)
[Source=AutoML, Kind=Trace] 2   NaN 00:00:00.5833636    xf=ColumnConcatenating{ col=Features:V1,V2,V3,V4,V5,V6} xf=Normalizing{ col=Features:Features} tr=SdcaLogisticRegressionBinary{}  cache=+
|2    SdcaLogisticRegressionBinary              NaN      NaN      NaN       NaN       0.6          0             |
System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: AUC is not definied when there is no positive class in the data
Parameter name: PosSample
   at Microsoft.ML.Data.EvaluatorBase`1.AucAggregatorBase`1.ComputeWeightedAuc(Double& unweighted)
   at Microsoft.ML.Data.BinaryClassifierEvaluator.Aggregator.Finish()
   at Microsoft.ML.Data.BinaryClassifierEvaluator.<>c__DisplayClass32_0.<GetAggregatorConsolidationFuncs>b__0(UInt32 stratColKey, ReadOnlyMemory`1 stratColVal, Aggregator agg)
   at Microsoft.ML.Data.EvaluatorBase`1.ProcessData(IDataView data, RoleMappedSchema schema, Func`2 activeColsIndices, TAgg aggregator, AggregatorDictionaryBase[] dictionaries)
   at Microsoft.ML.Data.EvaluatorBase`1.Microsoft.ML.Data.IEvaluator.Evaluate(RoleMappedData data)
   at Microsoft.ML.Data.BinaryClassifierEvaluator.Evaluate(IDataView data, String label, String score, String predictedLabel)
   at Microsoft.ML.AutoML.BinaryMetricsAgent.EvaluateMetrics(IDataView data, String labelColumn)
   at Microsoft.ML.AutoML.RunnerUtil.TrainAndScorePipeline[TMetrics](MLContext context, SuggestedPipeline pipeline, IDataView trainData, IDataView validData, String labelColumn, IMetricsAgent`1 metricsAgent, ITransformer preprocessorTransform, FileInfo modelFileInfo, DataViewSchema modelInputSchema, AutoMLLogger logger)
[Source=AutoML, Kind=Trace] Evaluating pipeline xf=ColumnConcatenating{ col=Features:V1,V2,V3,V4,V5,V6} tr=LightGbmBinary{}  cache=-
[Source=AutoML, Kind=Error] Pipeline crashed: xf=ColumnConcatenating{ col=Features:V1,V2,V3,V4,V5,V6} tr=LightGbmBinary{}  cache=- . Exception: System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: AUC is not definied when there is no positive class in the data
Parameter name: PosSample
   at Microsoft.ML.Data.EvaluatorBase`1.AucAggregatorBase`1.ComputeWeightedAuc(Double& unweighted)
   at Microsoft.ML.Data.BinaryClassifierEvaluator.Aggregator.Finish()
   at Microsoft.ML.Data.BinaryClassifierEvaluator.<>c__DisplayClass32_0.<GetAggregatorConsolidationFuncs>b__0(UInt32 stratColKey, ReadOnlyMemory`1 stratColVal, Aggregator agg)
   at Microsoft.ML.Data.EvaluatorBase`1.ProcessData(IDataView data, RoleMappedSchema schema, Func`2 activeColsIndices, TAgg aggregator, AggregatorDictionaryBase[] dictionaries)
   at Microsoft.ML.Data.EvaluatorBase`1.Microsoft.ML.Data.IEvaluator.Evaluate(RoleMappedData data)
   at Microsoft.ML.Data.BinaryClassifierEvaluator.Evaluate(IDataView data, String label, String score, String predictedLabel)
   at Microsoft.ML.AutoML.BinaryMetricsAgent.EvaluateMetrics(IDataView data, String labelColumn)
   at Microsoft.ML.AutoML.RunnerUtil.TrainAndScorePipeline[TMetrics](MLContext context, SuggestedPipeline pipeline, IDataView trainData, IDataView validData, String labelColumn, IMetricsAgent`1 metricsAgent, ITransformer preprocessorTransform, FileInfo modelFileInfo, DataViewSchema modelInputSchema, AutoMLLogger logger)
[Source=AutoML, Kind=Trace] 3   NaN 00:00:00.0955045    xf=ColumnConcatenating{ col=Features:V1,V2,V3,V4,V5,V6} tr=LightGbmBinary{}  cache=-
|3    LightGbmBinary                            NaN      NaN      NaN       NaN       0.1          0             |
System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: AUC is not definied when there is no positive class in the data
Parameter name: PosSample
   at Microsoft.ML.Data.EvaluatorBase`1.AucAggregatorBase`1.ComputeWeightedAuc(Double& unweighted)
   at Microsoft.ML.Data.BinaryClassifierEvaluator.Aggregator.Finish()
   at Microsoft.ML.Data.BinaryClassifierEvaluator.<>c__DisplayClass32_0.<GetAggregatorConsolidationFuncs>b__0(UInt32 stratColKey, ReadOnlyMemory`1 stratColVal, Aggregator agg)
   at Microsoft.ML.Data.EvaluatorBase`1.ProcessData(IDataView data, RoleMappedSchema schema, Func`2 activeColsIndices, TAgg aggregator, AggregatorDictionaryBase[] dictionaries)
   at Microsoft.ML.Data.EvaluatorBase`1.Microsoft.ML.Data.IEvaluator.Evaluate(RoleMappedData data)
   at Microsoft.ML.Data.BinaryClassifierEvaluator.Evaluate(IDataView data, String label, String score, String predictedLabel)
   at Microsoft.ML.AutoML.BinaryMetricsAgent.EvaluateMetrics(IDataView data, String labelColumn)
   at Microsoft.ML.AutoML.RunnerUtil.TrainAndScorePipeline[TMetrics](MLContext context, SuggestedPipeline pipeline, IDataView trainData, IDataView validData, String labelColumn, IMetricsAgent`1 metricsAgent, ITransformer preprocessorTransform, FileInfo modelFileInfo, DataViewSchema modelInputSchema, AutoMLLogger logger)
Exception occured while exploring pipelines:
Training failed with the exception: System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: AUC is not definied when there is no positive class in the data
Parameter name: PosSample
   at Microsoft.ML.Data.EvaluatorBase`1.AucAggregatorBase`1.ComputeWeightedAuc(Double& unweighted)
   at Microsoft.ML.Data.BinaryClassifierEvaluator.Aggregator.Finish()
   at Microsoft.ML.Data.BinaryClassifierEvaluator.<>c__DisplayClass32_0.<GetAggregatorConsolidationFuncs>b__0(UInt32 stratColKey, ReadOnlyMemory`1 stratColVal, Aggregator agg)
   at Microsoft.ML.Data.EvaluatorBase`1.ProcessData(IDataView data, RoleMappedSchema schema, Func`2 activeColsIndices, TAgg aggregator, AggregatorDictionaryBase[] dictionaries)
   at Microsoft.ML.Data.EvaluatorBase`1.Microsoft.ML.Data.IEvaluator.Evaluate(RoleMappedData data)
   at Microsoft.ML.Data.BinaryClassifierEvaluator.Evaluate(IDataView data, String label, String score, String predictedLabel)
   at Microsoft.ML.AutoML.BinaryMetricsAgent.EvaluateMetrics(IDataView data, String labelColumn)
   at Microsoft.ML.AutoML.RunnerUtil.TrainAndScorePipeline[TMetrics](MLContext context, SuggestedPipeline pipeline, IDataView trainData, IDataView validData, String labelColumn, IMetricsAgent`1 metricsAgent, ITransformer preprocessorTransform, FileInfo modelFileInfo, DataViewSchema modelInputSchema, AutoMLLogger logger)
System.InvalidOperationException: Training failed with the exception: System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: AUC is not definied when there is no positive class in the data
Parameter name: PosSample
   at Microsoft.ML.Data.EvaluatorBase`1.AucAggregatorBase`1.ComputeWeightedAuc(Double& unweighted)
   at Microsoft.ML.Data.BinaryClassifierEvaluator.Aggregator.Finish()
   at Microsoft.ML.Data.BinaryClassifierEvaluator.<>c__DisplayClass32_0.<GetAggregatorConsolidationFuncs>b__0(UInt32 stratColKey, ReadOnlyMemory`1 stratColVal, Aggregator agg)
   at Microsoft.ML.Data.EvaluatorBase`1.ProcessData(IDataView data, RoleMappedSchema schema, Func`2 activeColsIndices, TAgg aggregator, AggregatorDictionaryBase[] dictionaries)
   at Microsoft.ML.Data.EvaluatorBase`1.Microsoft.ML.Data.IEvaluator.Evaluate(RoleMappedData data)
   at Microsoft.ML.Data.BinaryClassifierEvaluator.Evaluate(IDataView data, String label, String score, String predictedLabel)
   at Microsoft.ML.AutoML.BinaryMetricsAgent.EvaluateMetrics(IDataView data, String labelColumn)
   at Microsoft.ML.AutoML.RunnerUtil.TrainAndScorePipeline[TMetrics](MLContext context, SuggestedPipeline pipeline, IDataView trainData, IDataView validData, String labelColumn, IMetricsAgent`1 metricsAgent, ITransformer preprocessorTransform, FileInfo modelFileInfo, DataViewSchema modelInputSchema, AutoMLLogger logger)
   at Microsoft.ML.CLI.CodeGenerator.CodeGenerationHelper.GenerateCode()
   at Microsoft.ML.CLI.Program.<>c__DisplayClass1_0.<Main>b__0(NewCommandSettings options)
Please see the log file for more info.
Exiting ...
```

Here is a small subset of the sample of data I am trying to train on. The training fails with the above error even if I use just this small subset. Note: the column "Res" is what I am asking the ML system to predict.

```
V1,V2,V3,V4,V5,V6,Res
1.04,0,0,93,0.93,30,1
1.33,3,0.6,81,0.81,37,1
1.2,3,0.6,90,0.9,30,1
1.13,0,0,74,0.74,19,1
1.06,0,0,78,0.78,18,1
1.25,3,0.6,86,0.86,21,1
1.25,4,0.8,89,0.89,18,0
1.25,5,1,96,0.96,23,0
```

It can be seen that there are indeed positive and negative labels in the "Res" column. Furthermore, I have tried varying the values in this column to be "True/False", "Yes/No", and "1/0" as seen here. Can anyone suggest a fix for this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The solution to this turned out to be that I was not loading enough data. Validation and test splits were being automatically generated, but there were some splits with no examples of the correct class.

I don't know if this is still an issue or not with the latest version as this was some time.

Load lots of data!

Answer (score 5):

How are you loading data, this could look like your label column is empty so maybe data is not loaded correctly. If using built in mlContext.Data.LoadFromTextFile remember that it defaults to TSV so you will have to specify seperator yourself in its configuration like this:

```
mlContext.Data.LoadFromTextFile<YourClass>(@"c:\path\to.file", separatorChar:',',hasHeader:true)
```

Comment: I had forgotten to enable header parsing and it drove me nuts until I found this. Thanks!

Comment: I just plain forgot to load the label column from the data source. Thanks both jakobandersen SergeantSerk for pointing me to that.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your Test and Training data must have true and false both kind of data, My Problem resolved once I included true and false, both kind of data in the Test and Training file/dataset.